# How to solve yaml file size issue with moulting yaml

Tags: scala, yaml, snakeyaml

we are using moultingyaml "0.4.1  is our project which is wrapper of snakeyaml  1.26 for Scala projects

```scala
import net.jcazevedo.moultingyaml._
```

i searched on google and got to know about one approach that we have to set something like below to change the yaml file limit

```scala
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new LoaderOptions()); 

yaml.getLoaderOptions().setMaxAliasesForCollections(1000000)
```

or

```scala
yaml.getLoaderOptions().setCodePointLimit(10000000)
```

According to link https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.26/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.html   in snakeyaml 1.26 there is no function defined as setCodePointLimit.

so we can't change codePointLimit .

can you please assist.

Comment: If you poke around the Javadoc you posted, you'll find that [`setCodePointLimit` was introduced in 1.32](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.32/org/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions.html), so your only option is to update your dependency to 1.32 or higher.